# Headers to column, pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, header

for example I have a pandas DataFrame of the test results in some class. It could look like this table:

| Name | English | French | History | Math | Physic | Chemistry | Biology |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 5 | 4 |
| Tom | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 5 |
| Nina | 5 | 6 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 5 |
| Anna | 4 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 3 |
| Musa | 5 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 6 | 5 |
| Maria | 4 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 3 |
| Chris | 6 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 6 |

For every student I want to create **at least** two columns with the best test result and best subject. Important: every student can have more than only one best subject (the results are similar)!

For the example above it should be look like this:

| Name | English | French | History | Math | Physic | Chemistry | Biology | Best result | Best subject 1 | Best subject 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mike | 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 6 | Physic | *None* |
| Tom | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 | Chemistry | Biology |
| Nina | 5 | 6 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 6 | French | *None* |
| Anna | 4 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 5 | Math | Physic |
| Musa | 5 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 6 | 5 | 6 | Chemistry | *None* |
| Maria | 4 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 5 | History | *None* |
| Chris | 6 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 6 | 6 | English | Biology |

what is the best way to do it in Pandas? Thank you in advance!

what is the best way to do it in Pandas? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution :

```
tmp = df.set_index("Name") # a DataFrame
bre = tmp.max(axis=1) # a Series

bsu = (
    ((tmp.columns + "|") @ tmp.eq(bre, axis=0).T)
        .str.strip("|").str.split("|", expand=True)
        .rename(lambda x: f"Best subject {x+1}", axis=1)
    )

out = tmp.assign(**{"Best result": bre}).join(bsu).reset_index()#.fillna("None")
```

Output :

|  | Name | English | French | History | Math | Physic | Chemistry | Biology | Best result | Best subject 1 | Best subject 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Mike | 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 6 | Physic |  |
| 1 | Tom | 4 | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 5 | Chemistry | Biology |
| 2 | Nina | 5 | 6 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 5 | 6 | French |  |
| 3 | Anna | 4 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 3 | 3 | 5 | Math | Physic |
| 4 | Musa | 5 | 5 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 6 | 5 | 6 | Chemistry |  |
| 5 | Maria | 4 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 5 | History |  |
| 6 | Chris | 6 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 6 | 6 | English | Biology |

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
best_result = df.select_dtypes(include="number").max(axis=1)
to_add = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        b.index[b == a]
        for a, (_, b) in zip(best_result, df.select_dtypes(include="number").iterrows())
    ]
)
to_add.columns = [f"Best subject {c + 1}" for c in to_add]
df = pd.concat([df.assign(**{"Best result": best_result}), to_add], axis=1)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    Name  English  French  History  Math  Physic  Chemistry  Biology  Best result Best subject 1 Best subject 2
0   Mike        3       3        4     5       6          5        4            6         Physic           None
1    Tom        4       4        3     4       4          5        5            5      Chemistry        Biology
2   Nina        5       6        4     3       3          3        5            6         French           None
3   Anna        4       3        4     5       5          3        3            5           Math         Physic
4   Musa        5       5        4     4       4          6        5            6      Chemistry           None
5  Maria        4       3        5     4       3          2        3            5        History           None
6  Chris        6       5        5     5       5          5        6            6        English        Biology
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculating `Best Result` is a simpler part of the task - just apply `max` to each row (considering only subject columns).

To get first two best subjects you can create a separate function to apply to each row (now including all subject columns and best result column). In this function create a list `best_subjects`, iterate through all subjects and append only those, where score is best. One best subject is guaranteed, the second is not - so just in case appending `None` in the end. `return pd.Series` makes the result of the application a dataframe, that can be concatenated to the original one.

```
def get_best_subjects(row):
    best_result = row["Best Result"]
    best_subjects = []
    for name, score in row.items():
        if name != "Best Result" and score == best_result:
            best_subjects.append(name)
    best_subjects.append(None)
    return pd.Series({
        "Best Subject 1": best_subjects[0],
        "Best Subject 2": best_subjects[1]
    })

subjects = df.columns[1:]
df["Best Result"] = df[subjects].apply(max, axis=1)
    
pd.concat([
    df,
    df[list(subjects.values) + ["Best Result"]].apply(get_best_subjects, axis=1)
], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    Name  English  French  History  Math  Physic  Chemistry  Biology  \
0   Mike        3       3        4     5       6          5        4   
1    Tom        4       4        3     4       4          5        5   
2   Nina        5       6        4     3       3          3        5   
3   Anna        4       3        4     5       5          3        3   
4   Musa        5       5        4     4       4          6        5   
5  Maria        4       3        5     4       3          2        3   
6  Chris        6       5        5     5       5          5        6   

   Best Result Best Subject 1 Best Subject 2  
0            6         Physic           None  
1            5      Chemistry        Biology  
2            6         French           None  
3            5           Math         Physic  
4            6      Chemistry           None  
5            5        History           None  
6            6        English        Biology
```